# Blending CSS Animation Iterations

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

Is there a way to blend between the iterations in a CSS animation? Consider [this example](http://codepen.io/KenPowers/pen/jkGKH). The animation gets to `100%` and then abruptly resets to `0%`. I want to get rid of that abrupt transition.

Comment: For your specific example, the problem seems to be that the last circle (the one at the very bottom), doesn't complete like the others--it expands but doesn't contract. If it did, the animation would surely be smooth? EDIT: never mind, thinking about it, it has to go like that because the next one animates simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of making the 0% keyframe and the 100% keyframe being identical. In your case,

```
0% {
  box-shadow:
    @tqua @tqua, // bottom right
    @double 0, // middle right
    @tqua -@tqua, // top right
    0 -@double, // top middle
    -@tqua -@tqua, // top left
    -@double 0, // middle left
    -@tqua @tqua, // bottom left
    0 @double 0 @resize; // bottom middle
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cbafz)